# SAS: Calculate Running Maximum and Minimum (Using Hash Objects)

Tags: sas

I am trying to do the following in SAS. Say that I have the following data coming from an auction book:

[image: Auction Book: Current]

I wish to populate the last four columns (Best Buy, Units Avail. at Best Buy, Best Sell, and Units Avail. at Best Sell) in SAS

[image: Auction Book: Current + Wanted]

Anyone one has any suggestion on how to compute the last four columns in SAS?

As you can see, these four last columns keep track of the best available price for a buy and sell and the number of units available at these prices at every period. Every time there is a better buy or sell price added to the "opportunities to buy" or "opportunities to sell" the last two columns must be updated. This is also true when there is a purchased or a sell of some units at the best available price.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. What is your definition of "best available price"? I thought it was simply a case of the lowest buy and highest sell so far, but your numbers jump up and down.

Comment: In the column "opportunities to buy", say until time=8, it means that there are people willing to sell you a unit at difference price (which varies between 80 and 82) hence the "best buy" available is 80.

Comment: I added two more columns that keeps track of the available units at the best buy and best sell. These two columns are crucial in my work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three options I can think of are (1) transpose and use data step arrays, (2) use double-ampersand macro arrays (3) create a hash object. Hash is probably your best bet. [Here](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/147-2012.pdf) is a good intro to hash.

I thought about using retain but I don't think that would work because when you buy or sell, it appears that you need to re-calculate the max selling price and min buying price, not including the price you bought or sold at.

Edit: :Below is how I used hash to make this work. First it sets up two datasets, one for selling and one for buying. Then in the next datastep it turns them both into hash objects. It refers to the hash objects when something is bought and sold to update quantity demanded/supplied, and to find the new best price and quantity at that price.

```
data hashset (keep=time2 buyprice2 ntobuy2 sellprice2 ntosell2);
    set book2;
    buyprice2=buyprice; ntobuy2=ntobuy; sellprice2=sellprice; ntosell2=ntosell; time2=time;
    if (buyprice2 ne .) or (sellprice2 ne .) then output;
run;

data bestprices;
    retain time buyprice ntobuy sellprice ntosell buy sell bestbuy nbestbuy tbestbuy bestsell nbestsell tbestsell;
    set book2 end=setdone;
    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        *Set up hash hh, which contains the data in the data set hashset, with the key time2;
        set hashset;
        declare hash hh(dataset:'hashset', ordered:'a');
        hh.definekey('time2');
        hh.definedata(all:'yes');
        hh.definedone();
        declare hiter hiter('hh'); *Hash iterator allows iterating through the hash;
    end;

    *Buy section;
    if (buyprice ne . and ((bestbuy=.) or (bestbuy>buyprice))) then do;
        bestbuy=buyprice; nbestbuy=ntobuy; tbestbuy=time;
    end;
    bamper=index(buy, '@');
    if bamper>0 then do;
        time2=tbestbuy;
        num=substr(buy, 1, bamper-1)*1;
        if hh.find()=0 then do;
            ntobuy2=ntobuy2-num;
            hh.replace();
            found=0;
            rc=hiter.first();
            do while(rc=0);
                if (ntobuy2>0) and (time2<time) and ((found=0) or (bestbuy>buyprice2)) then do;
                    found=1; 
                    bestbuy=buyprice2; nbestbuy=ntobuy2; tbestbuy=time2;
                end;
                rc=hiter.next();
            end;
        end;
    end;

    *Sell section;
    if (sellprice ne . and ((bestsell=.) or (bestsell<sellprice))) then do;
        bestsell=sellprice; nbestsell=ntosell; tbestsell=time;
    end;
    samper=index(sell, '@');
    if samper>0 then do;
        time2=tbestsell;
        num=substr(sell, 1, samper-1)*1;
        if hh.find()=0 then do;
            ntosell2=ntosell2-num;
            hh.replace();
            found=0;
            rc=hiter.first();
            do while(rc=0);
                if (ntosell2>0) and (time2<time) and ((found=0) or (bestsell<sellprice2)) then do;
                    found=1; 
                    bestsell=sellprice2; nbestsell=ntosell2; tbestsell=time2;
                end;
                rc=hiter.next();
            end;
        end;
    end;
    keep time buyprice ntobuy sellprice ntosell buy sell bestbuy nbestbuy bestsell nbestsell;
    if setdone then hh.output(dataset:'hh');
run;
```

Here is the code I used to set up the initial dataset. You shouldn't need it because you already have the dataset, but just for reference:

```
data book;
input buyprice sellprice buy $ sell $ ntobuy ntosell ;
datalines;
80      78      na      na      10  13
80.5    79.5    na      na      12  15
80.4    .       na      na      11  .
81      .       na      na      13  .
80.1    78.1    na      na      12  11
80.2    77      na      na      11  12
82      76      na      na      14  11
.       .       9@80    na      .   .
.       .       1@80    na      .   .
.       78.5    na      na      .   12
.       .       na      4@79.5  .   .
.       79      na      na      .   14
79.5    79.1    na      na      10  13
.       .       na      11@79.5 .   .
79.4    .       na      na      5   .
run;

data book;  
    retain time;
    set book;
    time = _n_;
    if buy = 'na' then buy = '';
    if sell = 'na' then sell = '';
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! You are right about the need to re-calculate the max selling price and min buying price and not including the price you bought or sold at. I will have the opportunity to test your code later or tomorrow. Thanks again and please let me know if it works also on your side once you have the chance to try it out.

Comment: I really want to downvote this answer but I won't because the suggestions are sound.  The reason for wanting to do this is because of your use of the lag functions within complex nested logic.  It's just asking for trouble.  Often lag functions used like this result in code that appears to be working but is actually returning incorrect results.  Especially as the data grows larger/more complex.  I think the best option out of those you suggested would be a hash.  When I have some time I will attempt a solution using that.

Comment: Looks like they changed the StackOverflow UI.  Couldn't undo my downvote because I made it 8mins ago. Sorry =/

Comment: @RobPenridge Thanks for the help! Can't wait to see your answer. I will read more on Hash Object.

Comment: I've also updated my question above with a little addition (which may complicate things more) but necessary for my analysis

Comment: @RobPenridge You can undo your downvote by clicking again on the downvote button: it's a toggle. That caught me out a few times too.

Comment: This should work now, the only think is I forgot to allow for multiple opportunities to buy at the same price. I'll work on an update to accomplish that, and I think in so doing I'll end up with a more concise code.

Comment: @catquas thanks a lot for the code and the help for me at understanding hash codes. I am curious to see the updates also for multiple opportunities to buy at the same price. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @catquas how can I adapt the code in order to also have the "second best available price" for both buy and sell? I am going through the code carefully with the Hash documentation to figure out.Thanks!

Comment: I updated it to allow for multiple options to buy/sell at the same price, and the code is more concise now too. I'll have to think about "second best".